# Flutter redux display alert dialog

Tags: mobile, flutter

I use the redux library in my application, i want to display an alert dialog in my widget according to certain conditions.

I have 3 different actions, in the middleware when one of these actions is requested, according to certain conditions i would like to display an alert dialog to notify my view with a message but i can't use my reducer to change my state with the message and notify a storeConnector because my dialog is a modal and not a Widget.

How can I do that ? I wanted to use Callback requested in my middleware instead of using my reducer. But because 3 actions can be used as output i can't use the action.callBack in my middleware.

Comment: Modals are widgets

Comment: Just subscribe to the store change from a widget and then on event call `showDialog()` from there.

Comment: Yes sorry alertDialog is a widget but, in my case, the way to display it does not return widget.  
Yes Günter Zöchbauer but where should I define my store connector in my widget if I just want display an alert dialog on it ? not on my build method, because if I use a stack widget for example, i need to return a widget from my sore connector. I’am new on flutter thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can listen to the Redux Store's stream directly without using a `StoreConnector` widget. You can do something like the following:

```
store.onChange.listen(() {
  if (shouldShowModal()) {
    showModal();
  }
});
```

Comment: How do I know that a specific variable changed?